# Memcached keys distribution

Tags: memcached, xmemcached

I'm using xmemcached client.
Is there a mechanism or best way to control from client side  the distribution of the keys
per server, i.e. I want to make sure all the keys following a certain custom  pattern to be stored in server1, while the others in server 2.

A simple example: all my keys starting with 'a' should go into server 1 while the others into server 2.

Comment: It's not possible.. clients cannot know anything about the server distribution. It would go against memcached basic idea and algorithm. And you will have probably less performance.

Comment: and btw if you need something like that, you probably don't need memcached.. memcached is a cache not a database or something where to store things..